# The function does not work synchronously, although I specified async / await

Tags: javascript

I want to read all the JSON files from the data folder. I use the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dir. I got a function, but it does not work synchronously. Variable `replacements` renders `undefined`.

```
async function giveHtml() {
    let replacements = await dir.readFiles(__dirname + '/data', { match: /.json$/ }, (err, content, next) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        next()
    })
    console.log(replacements)
    return replacements
}
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: Shouldn't the content be in the 'content' variable that you get as the param in the callback function?

Comment: @Franjo Pintarić Yes, it is there, but how can I get it back from the function?

Comment: When you call next you don't pass in any arguments

Comment: @MegaRoks The 'readFiles' function of that lib does not return any files, so you can't get them the way you are trying to. Have you read the docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only `await` a promise, and `dir.readFiles` does not return a promise.

You can either [convert it to use a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) or use [a module that already returns a promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-readfile-promise).

Comment: Note the `node-dir` module already has a `Promise`-based function. No need to convert or change modules. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dir#promisefiles-dir-callback-

Answer (score 1):

`dir.readFiles` does not seem to return a promise, it returns `undefined` so that's what you're getting in return. You can try creating your own promise like this.

```
function giveHtml() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dir.readFiles(__dirname + '/data', { match: /.json$/ }, (err, content, next) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      // do stuff per file if you want
      next()
    }, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      resolve(files)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your mistake is about not waiting for the response;
You are returning the var replacements before the answer is given.

I'd try to call

```
console.log(replacements)
```

after your

```
next()
```

Answer (score 0):

`async`/`await` is syntactic sugar for a JavaScript `Promise`. `await` is listening for a resolved `promise`. In the npm package you are using, the `readFiles` function works with a callback, not a promise.

Use the `promiseFiles` function call instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dir#promisefiles-dir-callback-